# In FME, how can I extract the last few characters from a string where each string is a different length?

Tags: coordinates, fme-form

I have two string attributes, for both of which I need to extract the last 5 characters from each string. The length of the strings varies, with some 6 and some 7 characters.

[image: In this example, I have 256175 and 1017775. I want to be able to pull out 56175 and 17775 respectively]

In this example, I have 256175 and 1017775. I want to be able to pull out 56175 and 17775 respectively

I have tried to use various string-based transformers, but have found that none will do this, and I will instead lose the wrong characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SubstringExtractor](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/substringextractor.htm) to do this, setting startindex to -5 and endindex to -1.

> Extracts a substring from the source attribute. The substring is taken from the range of characters specified.

Comment: That has done the trick, thank you. I wasn't aware that substring extractor could work where strings were different lengths.